# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error Issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, linker-errors, box2d-iphone

I've read a number of posts on this issue but I haven't found anything particularly helpful. I am trying to make a weldJoint when two sprites meet using a contact listener. I keep getting the following error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
"_touchingBodies", referenced from:
SubcContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact*) in SubcContactListener.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my contact listener.
SubcContactListener.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import <vector>
typedef std::pair<b2Body*, b2Body*> bodyPair;
typedef std::vector<bodyPair> thingsThatTouched;

extern thingsThatTouched touchingBodies;

class SubcContactListener : public b2ContactListener    {

public:

    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
void EndContact(b2Contact* contact);
};
```

SubcContactListener.mm:

```
#import "SubcContactListener.h"
void SubcContactListener:: BeginContact(b2Contact *contact) {

touchingBodies.push_back( std::make_pair(contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody(), contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()) );
}
```

I added:

```
 thingsThatTouched touchingBodies;
```

to the HelloWorldLayer.h interface.

Finally, in the tick method of the HelloWorldLayer.mm (after the timestep):

```
b2WeldJointDef weldJointDef;
 b2WeldJoint *weldJoint;

for (int i = 0; i < touchingBodies.size(); i++) {
    b2Body* bodyA = touchingBodies[i].first;
    b2Body* bodyB = touchingBodies[i].second;

    weldJointDef.Initialize(bodyA, bodyB, bodyA->GetWorldCenter());
    weldJointDef.collideConnected = false;
    weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef);

}
touchingBodies.clear();
```

Please help, I've been at it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern thingsThatTouched touchingBodies;
```

Such extern variables must be defined as static C variables elsewhere, not instance variables.

In light of a better design, I recommend to scrap the extern variable and instead access the touchingBodies through the HelloWorldLayer by adding a Singleton interface to it.

You'd then be able to access it from anywhere:

```
[HelloWorldLayer sharedWorldLayer].touchingBodies;
```